# Load SMB path in finder via command line

Tags: command-line, smb

I have an SMB path that I need to browse to in the finder. I used to do this all the time with the following:

```
open smb://path/to/directory
```

I just updated to Big Sur and now every time I do this, I get the following:

```
The file /Users/myusername/smb:/path/to/directory does not exist
```

Is there some way to make it stop looking for the SMB path in the current directory?

Answer (score 1):

Check `man open` from your Terminal.app:

```
% man open
```

Mine (Catalina) says:

> The open command opens a file (or a directory or URL), just as if you had double-clicked the file's icon. If no application name is specified, the default application as determined via LaunchServices is used to open the specified files.

And so it depends on the `LaunchServices` database - which maps/associates certain files and actions with their applications. For example, an Excel spreadsheet `*.xslx` is associated with the Excel application; a dbl-click on a `*.xslx` file will **launch** Excel, and open the file you dbl-clicked. So that's how it works in general. Unfortunately, its construction is not very well documented, and may be useless in this instance. But, FWIW, you can view its contents like so:

```
% /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -dump> LaunchServicesDump.txt 

# open the output file in the pager `less`: 

% less LaunchServicesDump.txt 

# search or browse; I didn't find much useful here
```

The problem you seem to be having here is that the *object* of your `open` command: `smb://path/to/directory` may have had some meaning on your old system, but it has none on your new `BigSur` system.

You didn't explain, and so I will hazard a guess that there were other steps/commands used to enable this to work on your old machine. I think there are two solutions to your problem:

#### Solution 1. Use `Finder` to first create a connection

This may be what you did on your old system. Try this:

###### Step 1.

Open `Finder`, click the `Go` item in the Menu, and then `Connect to server...` (or ,<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>)

###### Step 2.

Enter `smb://path/to/directory`, and click the `Connect` button - alternatively, click `Browse` to open a Finder window with all known network hosts & select one.

###### Step 3.

A `Finder` window will open showing all the files & folders from that network share. After you close that `Finder` window, that connection should now be *registered* in your `LaunchServices` database; i.e. you may type `open smb://path/to/directory` in Terminal.app, and Finder will open to that share.

#### Solution 2. Use the CLI to `mount` the SMB server on a local folder

###### Step 1.

Read `man mount` and `man mount_smbfs`. `mount_smbfs` is referred to as a "helper app" for the `mount` command, and its man page will contain information on the options you'll need to use with `mount`.

###### Step 2.

Try to `mount` your SMB server from the CLI (Terminal.app) using something like this - adjusted for your server & network situation:

```
% mount -t smbfs //userid:userpwd@SMBserverURL/sharename /Users/macuserid/local_folder_mntpoint
```

Where:

- userid - your user account name on the SMB server
- userpwd - your user password on the SMB server
- SMBserverURL - the IP address of your SMB server, or a *recognized* network name
- sharename - the shared folder on your SMB server you wish to access
- macuserid - your Mac username
- local_folder_mntpoint - the directory/folder on your Mac's **local** drive to use as the **mountpoint**

###### Step 3.

Once your `mount` command has succeeded, you should be able to open `Finder` to your mounted drive as follows:

```
open /Users/macuserid/local_folder_mntpoint
```

or, if your mountpoint is in your $HOME folder:

```
% cd        # go to $HOME folder
% open local_folder_mntpoint
```

#### An Alternative:

An alternative to the manual mount as shown above is to set up an `automount`. That's probably best answered under another question.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to leave such a thorough response. I'll try working through your suggestions as soon as I get a chance.